# JPA 2 criteria provide runtime type for gt operator

Tags: jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I am building a highly generic query mechanism on top of the JPA Criteria. I get as input an XML describing the query, something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Criteria xmlns='criteria' maxResults='2'>
    <Expression>
        <CompareRestriction propertyType='Date' operator='GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS' propertyName='deliveryDate'>2010-07-02</CompareRestriction>
        <CompareRestriction propertyType='Float' operator='GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS' propertyName='weight'>10f</CompareRestriction>
        <Restriction operator='NOT_NULL' propertyName='maxDiameter'/>
        <LogicalExpression operator='OR'>
           <LeftHandSideCompare propertyType="Integer" operator="EQUALS" propertyName="weight">31</LeftHandSideCompare>
           <RightHandSide operator='NOT_NULL' propertyName='lastChangedDate'/>
        </LogicalExpression>        
        <LogicalExpression operator='OR'>
           <LeftHandSideCompare propertyType="Integer" operator="EQUALS" propertyName="weight">31</LeftHandSideCompare>
           <RightHandSide operator='NOT_NULL' propertyName='lastChangedDate'/>
        </LogicalExpression>
     </Expression>
     <Order propertyName='deliveryDate' type='DESC'/>
</Criteria>
```

and I parse this thing and build the corresponding criteria. Currently I am facing a problem with it comes to comparison operators (<,>,<=,=>) as I deal with different numerical types: I have fields with Float, Integer or Long value. So when I am mapping I do something like this:

```
switch (leftHandSideCompareRestriction.getOperator().value()) {
...
case "LESS_THAN" : innerPredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.gt(rootQuery.<Number>get(propName), NumberUtils.createNumber((value))));
case "LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS" : innerPredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.gt(rootQuery.<Number>get(propName), NumberUtils.createNumber(value)));
...
}
```

The NumberUtils is the [apache commons NumberUtils utility class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#createNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

that returns a numerical type based on the input provided (Float, Integer, Long or Double). Now I need a mechanism to provide the type also for the

```
rootQuery<T>.get(propName)
```

at runtime, otherwise the JPA is complaining that I provided a Float instead of a Integer or the other way around. I tried several things and now I kind of ran out of ideas. I would highly appreciate and thoughts, ideas, suggestions about how to accomplish this in a robust fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that initially I missed something - I am not sure how. There some kind of issue in a different part. So, doing the query like this: it will work for sure. I tried with the following types:

```
Integer
Float
```

And it worked as expected for the following operations: >,<, <=, =>. In conclusion using Number and the NumberUtils fixes this issue in quite an elegant manner, as the appropriate type is created by the NumberUtils and JPA takes the top of the hierarchy for Number.